# How to set multiple validators to a field in web2py?

Tags: python, web2py

I wanna set multiple validators to a filed like this sample. but just one of them work well. why?

```
db.aetitles.hospital_id.requires = IS_NOT_EMPTY()
db.aetitles.hospital_id.requires = IS_IN_DB(db, db.hospitals.id, '%(title)s')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this and this was right:

```
db.aetitles.hospital_id.requires = [IS_NOT_EMPTY(),
                                IS_IN_DB(db, db.hospitals.id, '%(title)s')]
```

Comment: Yes. Note, in your first version, the second assignment simply overwrites the first assignment -- it does not append.

Comment: I tried with two validators and after adding the second one I do not get a drop down menu for the field referencing a table  anymore db.workers_skills.ws_skill.requires = [IS_IN_DB(db(db.skills.sk_organisation == org), db.skills.id, '%(sk_name)s', zero=T('Select skill')),
                                           IS_NOT_IN_DB(db(db.workers_skills.ws_worker == request.vars.ws_worker), 'workers_skills.ws_skill')]